# Handling of wrong URLs

Tags: bug

Being a very intelligent idiot :-), I more than once entered
"meta.chess.stackexchange.com" instead of the correct order. Firefox prompty panics with a "security risk". I tested a bit, the "standard" response on a site to an URL botched this way is a straight 404 error. Is there a technical reason (e.g. all the sites that *could* exist on SE in future) for the different handling? I tag it as "bug" now for lack of a better wording.

(To add lulz to injury, I tried to open the wrong URL with Lynx. Oh yes, Lynx. This will get me a kaput cookie and ultimatively redirect me to the correct page if I accept, as it seems. Thus it might be only due to Firefox.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not stupid, `meta.chess.stackexchange.com` *used to be* the domain of the Chess Meta site. Therefore, this link: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com still works and redirects to the current one, `chess.meta.stackexchange.com`.

However, I think Firefox interpreted your request as https://meta.chess.stackexchange.com (note the 's' in 'https'), and the Stack Exchange SSL certificate isn't valid for that domain. Therefore, Firefox displays a warning. If you choose to ignore the warning, you again get redirected to the right domain, `chess.meta.stackexchange.com`.

Details about the migration to HTTPS (quite technical though) can be found here: [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.